# Get SqlConnection from DbConnection

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, connection-string, mvc-mini-profiler

I have an Extension method on `DbContext` where I want to do a `SqlBulkCopy`. Therefore I need a `SqlConnection`. The connection from the DbContext is from the type `DbConnection` though. 
Among a few other things I tried this:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection( dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

Problem is that the password is missing (probably for security reasons).

Another thing that I tried is upcasting:

```
var bulk_copy = new SqlBulkCopy( (SqlConnection)dbContext.Database.Connection );
```

That actually presumes the DbConnection is a SqlConnection. In this very specific case it already goes wrong. I'm using the MVC MiniProfiler that wraps the connection into an `EFProfiledDbConnection`. EFProfiledDbConnection does not inherit from SqlConnection.

Any other ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, neither SqlConnection nor SqlBulkCopy do accept a DbConnection as constructor argument.

Comment: try upcasting the `DbConnection` to `SqlConnection`

Comment: Sorry, I tried that out already but forgot to add it to the question. I've updated my question.

Comment: Then try my approach - take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 21):

Well, if both can share the same `Connection String` then I guess they're both `SqlConnection`.

Try this instead:

```
var connection = rep.Database.Connection as SqlConnection;
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried that out already but forgot to add it to the question. I've updated my question.

Comment: To any future browsers looking at this question. While this answer doesn't work for the OP, in general DbConnection is often an instance of SqlConnection. So, you should check and see if this will work for your specific instance.

Answer (score 7):

One of the possible ways to work this around would be to add `Persist Security Info=true` to your connection string.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Persist Security Info. It sounds a bit drastic for something that hopefully can be solved a bit more elegant. What are the drawbacks?

Comment: Persist Security Info retains your password in memory, otherwise it is wiped out thus making your connection string unusable when trying to reuse it. I don't think there are drawbacks you should worry, assuming that the connection string is provided in the configuration file.

Comment: The most elegant approach would be to switch to integrated security so that there is no username/password in your connection string but rather - `Integrated security=true`.

Comment: Ok, is it something I'll take a look into! Integrated Security is not possible as I make use of SQL Azure.

Comment: There is then almost no risk with persisting the security info. Or rather - the risk is theoretical only.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with ProfiledConnection        (HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.ProfiledDataAccess.ProfiledConnection)

and what I needed was SqlConnection, this did the trick:

```
ProfiledConnection profiledConnection = dbContext.Database.Connection as ProfiledConnection;
SqlConnection sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)profiledConnection.Inner;
```

Answer (score 3):

Only way I found out so far is to use the System.Configuration library:

```
var sqlConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["your_conn_string_name"].ConnectionString;
var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnString);
```

Comment: sometimes you want to use an existing connection because of transactions rasons.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the newer .NET Core:

```
new SqlConnection(kontext.Database.GetConnectionString())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of `dbContext.Database.Connection`. If it is an `EFProfiledDbConnection`, you can get its `WrappedConnection` property, which returns a `DbConnection`. That is a `SqlConnection` if you use SQL Server.

Comment: I might do this if there is really no other solution. But I think it is quite ugly. Checking for types smells like bad code, and is something I rather prevent. This also means adding a reference to MiniProfiler in this assembly (MiniProfiler is now only referenced in my Web assembly). Another disadvantage is that there might be another type of DbConnection in the future that I don't have taken into account, and the code breaks again.

Comment: You can wrap it up in the context itself, e.g. in a `GetConnection()` method. Other assemblies wouldn't need a reference to MiniProfiler.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```cs
SqlConnection sqlConn = dbContext.Database.GetConnection<SqlConnection>()
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use:

```cs
(SqlConnection)context.Database.GetDbConnection()
```

That creates a copy of your SQL connection object with the pass included.

Comment: Not a copy. "Gets the underlying ADO.NET DbConnection for this DbContext." And the question states that this connection is not what they want.